# when() refering for different argument in testNG mocking

Tags: java, spring, mocking, testng

I have this methoid in `ReferenceConceptServiceImpl` class for testing and I used Mocking here.

```
@Resource
  private ReferenceConceptDTOMapper referenceConceptDtoMapper;

@Resource
  private TerminologyDefinitionDTOMapper definitionDTOMapper;

    public ReferenceConceptDTO getConceptByTerminologyAndId(final TerminologyDefinitionDTO terminology,
                                                              final String conceptId)
      {
        TerminologyDefinition terminologyDefinition = definitionDTOMapper.load(terminology);
        final ReferenceConcept findRefernaceConceptsByTermAndId = getDAO()
            .findReferenceConceptByTermAndId(terminologyDefinition, conceptId);

        return referenceConceptDtoMapper.convert(findRefernaceConceptsByTermAndId);
      }
```

and the constructor of my class is:

```
public ReferenceConceptServiceImpl(final se.cambio.concept.terminology.dto.spi.ReferenceConceptEntityDTOMapper<D> mapper,
                                     final se.cambio.concept.terminology.dto.spi.ReferenceConceptMutableEntityDTOMapper<MD> mutableMapper,
                                     final se.cambio.concept.terminology.persistence.ReferenceConceptDAO dao)
  {
    super(mapper, mutableMapper, dao);
  }
```

I added xml file with including the testable class bean and its dependencies too.
Also I added required dependencies to the test class and trying to test above method.It is like:

```
@Test
  public void testGetConceptByTerminologyAndId()
  {
    String conceptId = "test_Concept";
    when(definitionDTOMapper.load(getTerminologyDefinitionDTO())).thenReturn(getTerminologyDefinition());
    when(referenceConceptServiceImpl.getDAO()).thenReturn(mockReferenceConceptDAO);
    when(mockReferenceConceptDAO.findReferenceConceptByTermAndId(getTerminologyDefinition(), conceptId))
        .thenReturn(getReferenceConcept());
    when(referenceConceptDtoMapper.convert(getReferenceConcept())).thenReturn(getReferenceConceptDTO());
    ReferenceConceptDTO actualOutput = referenceConceptServiceImpl .getConceptByTerminologyAndId(getTerminologyDefinitionDTO(), conceptId);
    assertEquals(actualOutput, getReferenceConceptDTO());
  }
```

here the all getter methods have data. My problem is,
   After the calling `getDAO()` method it returns DAO kind of object. So then I tried to call `findReferenceConceptByTermAndId`by getting the output of getDAO().

problem is oiccur in that line.

**when(referenceConceptServiceImpl.getDAO()).thenReturn(mockReferenceConceptDAO);**

The error is :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.
```

Can some one clarrify the solutio for my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My self found a solution and I post it here;

What I did here is add following code :

```
when(referenceConceptServiceImpl.getDAO()findReferenceConceptByTermAndId(getTerminologyDefinition(), conceptId)).thenReturn(getReferenceConcept());
```

insted of following both lines:

```
 when(referenceConceptServiceImpl.getDAO()).thenReturn(mockReferenceConceptDAO);
    when(mockReferenceConceptDAO.findReferenceConceptByTermAndId(getTerminologyDefinition(), conceptId))
        .thenReturn(getReferenceConcept());
```